# How to force Kentico to generate lowercase urls by default?

Tags: c#, content-management-system, kentico

Here is an example how to modify global.asax.cs to achieve this, however this works only for version 3.x as the global.asax.cs source code is different in ver 4.1: http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums.aspx?ForumID=19&Thread=00004982

So I need a solution for 4.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In 4.1 you can run this SQL script to update the URLs

update CMS_DocumentAlias set AliasURLPath = LOWER(AliasURLPath)